# Pairing retropie with controllers: what does this error mean?

Tags: bluetooth, retropie, gamepad

I am trying to pair my retropie with two [8BITDO SFC30](http://www.8bitdo.com/sfc30/) gamepads.

To do so, I start them in the appropriate mode (pressing START+B on one and START+RIGHT+B on the other). I then connect them with this script:

```
sudo bluez-test-device remove $1
sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 $1 -c DisplayYesNo
sudo bluez-test-device trusted $1 yes
sudo bluez-test-input connect $1
```

I am confident the above steps are correct, but I get a `dbus` exception. For example:

```
pi@retropie ~ $ sudo ./connect.sh 01:02:03:04:05:06 
Release
New device (/org/bluez/2270/hci0/dev_01_02_03_04_05_06)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bluez-test-input", line 40, in <module>
    input.Connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Connect" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Input" doesn't exist
```

Any info I could find on the interwebs is useless. I strongly suspect it's a bug, but I don't know what it means.

What does this error mean? How do I debug it?

Comment: I went around the problem, [see here](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/issues/1153). however an answer to this would still be useful.